# Write byte to Arduino from Ruby over serial

Tags: ruby, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to send an integer over the serial port to my Ardunio. The chip is then going to display the number in binary on the LED's. However I'm having lots of trouble trying to send the data as a byte over the serial port, as far as I can debug the following code sends it as the ASC char values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or spot the mistake? I'd really appreciate it. I've been pulling my hair out over this for a long time.

**Ruby**

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'serialport' # use Kernel::require on windows, works better.  

#params for serial port  
port_str = "/dev/tty.usbserial-A700dZt3"  #may be different for you  
baud_rate = 9600  
data_bits = 8  
stop_bits = 1  
parity = SerialPort::NONE  

sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)  

i = 15

#just write forever  
while true do  
  sp.write(i.to_s(2))
  sleep 10
end
```

**Arduino**

```
int ledPin = 10;
int ledPin1 = 11;
int ledPin2 = 12;
int ledPin3 = 13;

byte incomingByte;  // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT); // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT); // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT); // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  Serial.println("I am online"); 
}

void loop() {
 // send data only when you receive data:
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
            Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);

   int value = (incomingByte, DEC) % 16;
   digitalWrite(ledPin, (value >> 0) % 2);
   digitalWrite(ledPin1, (value >> 1) % 2);
   digitalWrite(ledPin2, (value >> 2) % 2);
   digitalWrite(ledPin3, (value >> 3) % 2); // MSB

}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a terminal program instead of Ruby? Is this your first setup or did you already have something working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to write the value 15 in order to light all the LEDs at once. However, `15.to_s(2)` is "1111". The ASCII value of the character '1' is 49, so instead of writing 15 once you are writing 49 four times in rapid succession.

The write command you are looking for is therefore probably `sp.putc(i)`. This writes only one character with the given binary *value* (= machine-readable for Arduino) instead of an ASCII string representation of the value expressed in binary (= human-readable for you).

So keeping everything else the same, replace the `while` loop in your Ruby code with:

```
loop do
  sp.putc(i)
  puts 'Wrote: %d = %bb' % [ i, i ]
  i = (i == 15) ? 0 : (i + 1)
  sleep(10)
end
```

If you wish to read the responses from Arduino, you can use e.g. `sp.gets` to get one line of text, e.g. try placing `puts 'Arduino replied: ' + sp.gets` in the loop before `sleep` (and one `puts sp.gets` before the loop to read the "I am online" sent when the connection is first established).

**Edit:** I just spotted another problem in your code, on the Arduino side: `value = (incomingByte, DEC) % 16;` always results in the value 10 because `(incomingByte, DEC)` has the value `DEC` (which is 10). You should use `value = incomingByte % 16;` instead. Or do away with `value` altogether and modify `incomingByte` itself, e.g. `incomingByte %= 16;`.

Comment: As a minor optimization on the microcontroller, with your pin assignments 10-13 you could also replace the `digitalWrite` lines with (one) `PORTB = ((incomingByte & 0x0F) << 2) | (PORTB & 0xC3);`.

Comment: I'm endorsing this answer, it has most of what I was going to say. Also, though, the `digitalWrite(ledPin, (value >> 0) % 2);` lines might be an issue. I don't know if it is safe to assume HGIH and LOW map to 1 and 0. And usually pin 13 is an iffy pin to use, because it has a built in resistor.

Comment: Yes, `HIGH` and `LOW` map to 0 and 1. =) What is _not_ safe to assume is that the bits in `PORTB` map to specific physical pins but this is only an issue if moving to a different µC in which case the physical connections could also be moved. (If the corresponding pins on `PORTB` are available.)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this Ruby code work before

```
while true do
  printf("%c", sp.getc)
end
```

rather than using `sp.write(i.to_s)`.  It looks like you are explicitly converting it to a string, which may be the cause of your problems.

I found the original blog post I used:
http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Ruby

Answer (score 1):

It's been so long since I did anything with serial ports that I can't help there, but I do see one thing.

```
>> 15.to_s #=> "15"
```

and

```
>> 15.to_s(2) #=> "1111"
```

I think if you want the binary value to be sent you'll want `"\xf"` or `"\u000F"`.

---

Change your code from:

```
while true do  
  sp.write(i.to_s(2)) # <-- this sends a multi-character ASCII representation of the "i" value, NOT the binary.
  sleep 10
end
```

to:

```
while true do  
  sp.write(i.chr) # <-- this sends a single byte binary representation of the "i" value, NOT the ASCII.
  sleep 10
end
```

To show the difference, here's the length of the strings being output:

```
>> 15.to_s(2).size #=> 4
>> 15.chr.size #=> 1
```

And the decimal values of the bytes comprising the strings:

```
>> 15.to_s(2).bytes.to_a #=> [49, 49, 49, 49]
>> 15.chr.bytes.to_a #=> [15]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I tried it with sp.write 9.to_s(2) but it still doesnt seem to want to work.

Comment: Well, `9.to_s(2)` is not a binary representation of 9. It is a String representation. You'd have to use something like `"\x9"` or `"\x0009"` or `[9].pack('c')`. There's a difference between visually looking like the binary representation and *being* the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems may be caused by buffering. To disable buffering, you can do one of the following:

- [Set `sp` to unbuffered](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002263) after creating it (before writing): `sp.sync = true`
- Call [flush](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002278) after the `write`
- Use the unbuffered [syswrite](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002257) instead of write

Comment: Or set `sp.sync = true` immediately after the port is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys ive added  sp.sync = true but it still doesnt seem to work correctly